# angularjs jasmine testng - How do I mock a resource for a factory

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, factory

I can succesfully mock a resource for a controller, but I am unsure how to do so for a factory.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
       $scope = $injector.get('$scope');
       $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
       var $q = $injector.get('$q');
       $controller('mycontroller', {
           $q: $q, 
           name: resourceMock, 
       });
```

I have a factory that takes a Resource for an argument, but I am unsure of in a test how to have the factory use the mocks.

my test for the factory is usually:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(MyFactory, $q, Resource) {
        _factory = MyFactory;
}));
```

How do i test this so that I can access the methods of MyFactory via the global variable in my tests (or some other way, I dont have to use global variables, just want to be able to access the methods) and mock out "Resource")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer from another question.

in another beforeEach use the provide

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('oneOfMyOtherServicesStub', {
        someVariable: 1
    });
  }));
```